# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm tying to move some uploaded files to a directory but when I do it it becames this error:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/marc/Disco/Projects/Gym/uploads/images'

Here is the code:

```
routerProgress.post("/home/upload-progress", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const user_id = req.user.id;
  const weight = req.body.weight;
  const front = req.files.front;
  const from_side = req.files.from_side;
  const backwards = req.files.backwards;
  const front_id = `${v4()}-${front.name}`;
  const from_side_id = `${v4()}-${from_side.name}`;
  const backwards_id = `${v4()}-${backwards.name}`; 

  const dirname = '/home/marc/Disco/Projects/Gym/uploads/images';

  front.mv(dirname, front_id, (req, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("File Uploaded");
  })

  from_side.mv(dirname, from_side_id, (req, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("File Uploaded");
  })

  backwards.mv(dirname, backwards_id, (req, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("File Uploaded");
  })

  res.redirect("/home");
});
```

If anyone know what I should do to solve this issue I would be very grateful with him.